# Загрузка и конвертация изображения в Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity3d

Метод генерирует капчу с ключом и ссылкой на изображение. Соответственно изображение загружаю с **WWW**(*url*). Но, дело вот в чем, изображение генерируется в *.gif* формате, что осложняет дальнейшую работу с ним, т.к. Unity3D принимает лишь *.png* и *.jpg*. Собственно вопрос: т.к. движок не поддерживает **System.Drawning**, каким способом можно загрузить в спрайт это изображение?

Т.к. запуск игры будет производится при нажатии кнопки в Windows Forms, то возникла идея мониторить папку для временных данных, ловить загруженное и записанное в файл изображение, конвертировать его, и грузить в движок уже сконвертированное, или попробовать перерисовать попиксельно в текстуру.

Comment: >>Метод генерирует капчу с ключом и ссылкой на изображение.<< какой метод? Попробуйте из вашего gif файла прочитать и получить BitMap, чтобы не сохранять его в файл, а сразу отрисовать средствами юнити

Answer (score 2):

Если сборка WindowsStandalone, то System.Drawning прикрутить можно -- просто найти подходящую версию библиотеки опытным путём. Чтение, конвертация и запись изображений там будут доступны. Может понадобиться ещё System.dll в Plugins.